# Simultaneously download from server in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a listview and each of which contains a button. Each item in listview has different content so if button clicked it is supposed to download contents from web server. However, user can click two or three buttons while downloading and the downloading process should be running simultaneously. How to download clicked buttons' content from server simultaneously if more than one button clicked. I used asynctask but it only downloads one at the time. What other ways I could use? Any help would be very grateful.

Thanks;

Comment: You can choose to use DownloadManager, it saves you alot of work, just Google for how

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
task.execute();
```

You can use:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Which means the async tasks can execute in parallel. Note, the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) advise against this.